# Как получить значение тега с помощью регулярного выражения

Tags: регулярные-выражения

У меня есть xml вида

```
<ex:student>
 <ex:address>Германия
</ex:address>
</ex:student>
<university>
 <address>Россия</address>
 <strudent_address>Россия</strudent_address>
</university>
```

Я пытаюсь получить значение тегов address. Я написала регулярку, и хотя она отдает корректный результат, я не уверена, что она оптимальна и корректна
Регулярка: `/<(|.*?:)address>(\s*.*?\s*)<[\/].*?address>/ig`
Верно ли я написала регулярку?

Comment: а что мешает парсить сам xml?

Comment: Стандартными парсерами  какого-нибудь языка? То, что неизвестно, будет ли xml вообще валидной, а вытащить, даже из невалидной, информацию нужно

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/O3He9O/1 - как вариант

Comment: @PotroNik Спасибо. Только чуть докрутила вместо `(.*)` написала `(.*?)` так как иначе пустые теги не отлавливались. А еще можете немного объяснить конструкцию (?!\/)((?:.*?:)?

Comment: @Violetta `(?!\/)` -  негативный просмотре вперед, используется для поиска открывающего тега, `(?:.*?:)?` - необязательная  группа  состоящая из любого количества символов но в конце должно быть двоеточие, как пример отображен захват данной группы `abc:`dsdsds

Answer (score 1):

Лучше, конечно, парсить XML сообразными средствами, потому что регулярки плохо подходят для разбора XML и HTML. Но если нет другого выхода, вашу можно немного улучшить:

1. `(|.*?:)` — чем использовать альтернативу с пустой строкой, можно весь фрагмент сделать опциональным.
2. `(\s*.*?\s*)` — возможно, будет проще использовать флаг `s`, если ваш язык его поддерживает.
3. `[\/]` — использовать класс для одного символа вроде бы избыточно.
4. `.*?address` — слишком широко, может остановится на вложенном теге, где `address` лишь часть имени. Можем заменить обратной ссылкой на пространство имён открывающего тега (если его не было, в ссылке будет пустая строка).

У меня получился такой вариант на JS:

```js
const xml = `
<ex:student>
  <ex:address>Германия
  </ex:address>
</ex:student>
<university>
  <address>Россия</address>
  <strudent_address>Россия</strudent_address>
</university>`;

const re = /<(.+?:)?address>(.*?)<\/\1address>/igs;

const addresses = xml.match(re);

console.log(addresses);
```

Comment: У меня как раз в таком варианте захватывает часть чужого тега

Comment: Можете привести пример?